# Analisar arquivo txt e retornar em outro arquivo - Python

Tags: python, loop, while, txt

Boa noite!

Tem um arquivo com números, salvo em formato txt, cada número separado por espaço, havendo uma lista com cerca de 50 valores em cada linha do arquivo txt (e mais de 10.000 linhas no arquivo):
78 34 85 67 96 197 etc

Quero criar um programa python que compare 3 variáveis dentro do programa com cada linha do arquivo txt. Se o programa chegar ao final de todas linhas do arquivo de texto e não encontrar os 3 valores, vai retornar os 3 parâmetros de busca num arquivo de saída, incrementa as variáveis no loop e recomeça.

Por exemplo, o programa começa rodando com variáveis 30 31 e 32. Vai varrendo linha a linha. Se chegar ao final da última linha do arquivo texto e não tiver achado os 3 valores, retorna esses valores num arquivo de saída e recomeça a analisar o arquivo de texto com o valor de uma das variáveis incrementado. Se achar os 3 valores antes da linha final do arquivo, interrompe a busca, incrementa a variável e recomeça a busca na primeira linha do arquivo.

Comment: Pode postar o código que já tentou e o problema específico que teve que te travou de chegar no final?

Comment: E não ficou tão claro quanto a saída que deverá ser gerada. Tem como criar um [mcve], colocando parte do arquivo com os números, um exemplo da entrada e qual deverá ser a saída?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema...

Para ler o arquivo, usei:
    file_i = open(nome_arquivo_entrada, 'r')

Usei a instrução a seguir para armazenar as linhas do arquivo (pois vai ser necessário ler o mesmo arquivo várias vezes):
    entradatxt = file_i.readlines()

Criei 3 estruturas de repetição for usando contadores i, j e k:

```
nums = [i,j,k]  # objeto com os 3 índices para comparação com a linha do 
                # arquivo txt
for linha in entradatxt:
    lista = linha.rstrip().split(" ") #atribuição da linha a uma lista
    lista = list(map(int, lista)) #conversão dos valores para int
                          # pois estava dando erro na set(nums) & set(lista)
    ocorrencias = set(nums) & set(lista) #comparação lista e índices
    if (len(ocorrencias) != 0):
        break

    if (k==300):
        aprumando = str(sorted(nums)) #para ordenar os índices)
        aprumando = aprumando +"\n" #quebra de linha
        file_o.write(aprumando) #adicionando no arquivo saída
file_o.close()
```

Com certeza tem jeito de simplificar e tornar melhor a execução, mas desse jeito está atendendo...

Valeu, pessoal!